# UIActivityViewControllerで改行を含む文字列を渡して、Evernoteで共有しようとすると改行後が表示されない。

Tags: swift

下のようにすると、Evernoteでは

TEXT1

と改行前の部分だけが表示されます。

Twitterやメールを選んだ場合は、

TEXT1
TEXT2
TEXT3

と改行を含んで全てが渡されます。

Evernoteでも同様に全てが表示される方法はありますか？

```
@IBAction func actionButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

            let items = ["TEXT1\nTEXT2\nTEXT3"] //EvernoteではTEXT1と表示される

            // 渡したいデータを指定してインスタンスを生成
            let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)

            // UIActivityViewControllerを表示
            self.presentViewController(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

同じところで詰まっていて、わかったことを共有します。(Evernote8.0.4にて実施)

UIActivityViewControllerでEvernoteを選択した場合、表示(編集)出来るのはタイトルに当たる部分だけのようです。
実際にEvernote側に送信すると改行まで含んだテキスト(今回の場合"TEXT1\nTEXT2\nTEXT3")が改行込みで送られています。

逆に、その部分に表示をしてしまうと全てがタイトルとして扱われるようになります。
さらにテキストとして送信した部分もEvernote側に送信されてしまいます。

ご参考になれば幸いです。